# TypeError: alpha must be numeric or None, not a string

Tags: python, matplotlib, обработка-ошибок, визуализация

есть код:

```
from numpy import*
import pandas as pd
from pylab import*
import scaleogram as scg

ns = 1024
time = arange(ns)
scales = scg.periods2scales(arange(1, 40))
pulses = zeros(ns, dtype=float32)
steps = linspace(0, ns, 8)
periods = [10, 20, 40]
for i in range(0, 3):
    step_mask = (time > steps[i*2+1]) & (time < steps[i*2+2])
    pulses += cos(2*pi/periods[i]*time) * step_mask

fig1, ax1 = subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7, 3))
lines = ax1.plot(pulses); ax1.set_xlim(0, len(time))
ax1.set_title("Три импульса запускаются в разное время"); ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
fig1.tight_layout()

ax2 = scg.cws(pulses, scales = scales, figsize = (7, 3))
for i in range(0, 3):
    txt = ax2.annotate("p%d=%ds"%(i+1,periods[i]), xy=(steps[i*2]+20, periods[i]),
                       bbox=dict(boxstyle="round4", fc="w"))
    ax2.plot(steps[i*2+1]*np.ones(2), ax2.get_ylim(), '-w', alpha = 0.5)
    ax2.plot(steps[i*2+2]*np.ones(2), ax2.get_ylim(), '-w', alpha = 0.5)
tight_layout()
show()
```

Выдает ошибку,

> TypeError: alpha must be numeric or None, not a string

и

> File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line
> 21, in 
> ax2 = scg.cws(pulses, scales = scales, figsize = (7, 3))

Не могу понять в чем причина, пробовал менять и подставлять значения в переменную alpha в конце кода, но как я понял эта переменная не влияет на возникновение ошибки. Указывает на 21 строчку, дальше туман.

scg.cws из библиотеки scaleogram

Полный Traceback:

```
    C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rsupr/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    ax2 = scg.cws(pulses, scales = scales, figsize = (7, 3))
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\scaleogram\cws.py", line 264, in cws
    ax.fill_between(xmesh, yborder, ymask, **coikw )
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5252, in fill_between
    return self._fill_between_x_or_y(
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5238, in _fill_between_x_or_y
    collection = mcoll.PolyCollection(polys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1187, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1066, in update
    ret.append(func(v))
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 834, in set_alpha
    artist.Artist._set_alpha_for_array(self, alpha)
  File "C:\Users\rsupr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 989, in _set_alpha_for_array
    raise TypeError("alpha must be numeric or None, not a string")
TypeError: alpha must be numeric or None, not a string

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Код был взят из [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/454240/), из листинга *Три импульса*

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях надо очень внимательно читать `error traceback` и анализировать [исходники модулей](https://github.com/alsauve/scaleogram/blob/master/lib/scaleogram/cws.py). Возможно у вас сломанная версия модуля `scaleogram`.

Попробуйте так:

```
coikw = {'alpha': 0.5, 'hatch': '/'} # параметры по умолчанию, взято из исходника
ax2 = scg.cws(pulses, scales = scales, figsize = (7, 3), coikw=coikw)
```